# OPSHub installation issue

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We are using OPSHub free version for migrating On-Premises TFS 2013 to cloud (VSO 2015).

During Opshub installation we got an error  message "Unable to connect  to remote server, check the internet connectivity or Proxy settings and try again".

We found the following link http://www.opshub.com/main/ovsomu-proxy regarding this issue and we contacted our network team to get the proxy server details (to put them in the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS), but they would like to know how Opshub connects to internet and all the inbound and outbound connections from Opshub, which port it uses and if the data is encrypted during installation and migration etc. Can Opshub support help us out in providing this information?

Answer (score 0):

OpsHub use the standard VSTS ports of https which is encrypted with SSL. There are no inbound coms.

I would however not recommend the OpsHub tool as you will quickly run into an upsell from them. If it works for you then awesome, but if they as you for money then switch to the TFS Integration Tools that are free and supported by the TFS product team.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OVSMU requires to connect to the OpsHub website during installation for Verification Code generation process. (Thereafter, it does not connect to our website)

Once, the utility has been installed, it occupies two ports 8989 and 9090 as long as the tool is running. For communication with end points, it uses the default TFS and VSTS ports.

Comment: We are also getting same error "Unable to connect to remote server, check the internet connectivity or Proxy settings and try again". We are getting this error during registration process. What port OPShub uses during installation process (after providing First name, company name, address and other details during registration), what port it connects on OPShub to save the details and generate Verification code. (As I am getting error at this step).

Comment: The application uses HttpClient to connect to the OpsHub Website. The server side port is by default 80. On the client end however it's dynamic (based on which port is available)

Comment: When the installer is running and the error pop-up showed, go to Task Manager, select the OpsHub installer under processes (in Win 10) it might be under Java. Right click it and select "Open File Location". In the explorer, go two levels up until the (dot)tmp folder. Search for the file InstallationLog.log and see what the contents say.